# SQL Check Constraint in Subquery - Sybase

Tags: sql, database, sybase

I'm trying to add a Constraint to a Sybase table to check that two user provided values exist in a reference table to ensure their validity, some dates on the form they're submitting also have to match some date criteria within the same reference table.

However it does not appear that Sybase allows subqueries within CHECK constraints?
I've provided below what I've come up with so far.

Any help on how I could get round this would be great.

```
ALTER TABLE accomodation_t
  ADD CHECK (accomodation_t.requested_type_code, accomodation_t.provided_type_code IN
(SELECT(ref.accom_req_typ_cde, ref.accom_prov_typ_cde 
   FROM acc_type_ref_t ref,  accomodation_t ac 
    WHERE ac.accm_recd_date >= ref.eff_date 
     AND (ref.term_dte = '01/01/1900' OR ac.accom_recd_dte <= ref.term_dte))))
```

Comment: Instead use a `insert after` trigger.

Comment: Not really possible as it should not allow an insert if these field criteria aren't met

Answer (score 0):

Use `insert before` trigger. Moreover, you should always avoid having a derived check constraint like this. Triggers are much preferable in this type of scenario.

I have not worked on sybase before but below would be a sample to start with

```
CREATE TRIGGER check_constraint_trigger BEFORE INSERT
ON accomodation_t FOR EACH STATEMENT
BEGIN
accomodation_t.requested_type_code, 
accomodation_t.provided_type_code IN
(SELECT(ref.accom_req_typ_cde, ref.accom_prov_typ_cde 
   FROM acc_type_ref_t ref,  accomodation_t ac 
    WHERE ac.accm_recd_date >= ref.eff_date 
     AND (ref.term_dte = '01/01/1900' OR ac.accom_recd_dte <= ref.term_dte)))
END
```